# Start firefox in fullscreen using wmctrl

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, wmctrl

I wanted to know if the Firefox's config file can be edited such that Firefox starts in fullscreen. I wanted to find out where is Firefox's config file, so that I could go on and add this line there

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

For example I added this line to `.bashrc` and now my terminal emulator starts in fullscreen. What is the equivalent of `.bashrc` for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default size of the Firefox window is easy. Just change the settings of the file xulstore.json in your Firefox profile (while Firefox is closed).

For instance I changed the settings as follows, as the resolution of my screen is 1920x1080:
`"main-window":{"screenX":"0","screenY":"0","width":"1920","height":"1080","sizemode":"maximized"}`

However, I am not sure if you really refer to the fullscreen mode or if you rather refer to the resolution.

I have for instance a mini PC with Linux on it for the TV device where I almost only use Firefox. As the PC is very slow but I don’t want to decommission it yet, I want to start Firefox only so that there are no other X applications running in the background, like `startx firefox` instead of `startx` only.

I found the solution here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i
The solution was to put the necessary xrandr commands either in the /etc/X11/Xsession or in the ~/.xinit file.

Then in the folder /usr/share/xsessions/ I created a file “firefox.desktop" with the following entries:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=firefox
Name=Firefox
Comment=Start Firefox only
```

Like that, instead of starting my favourite window manager XFCE, I can select Firefox.

Nevertheless, there are still some problems. It is for instance not possible to use the Firefox Menu properly, because when I click on something it immediately closes again. Secondly, there is still an unused section on the background, so Firefox still doesn’t use the full height of 1080px. I suppose Firefox is simply not able to start completely alone.

Therefore, finally I decided to install the very lightweight Windows Manager Awesome (`sudo apt install awesome`).

Then, to enable autostart of Firefox in awesome, I entered the following code at the very end of the configuration file /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua (make a backup of that file before doing that).

```
autorun = true
autorunApps =
{
   "firefox",
}
if autorun then
   for app = 1, #autorunApps do
       awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app])
   end
end
```

Now it starts awesome + Firefox. The performance of videos is now much better than on XFCE, which is a leightweight window manager, but in comparison to awesome, it is actually heavy.

Finally, to shut down the system, I enter the shortcut “Mod4 (Windows) + Shift + q” to get back to the login console and shut down from there.

I hope that helps.